# How I make a SUM Function in MYSQL with Dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sum

Hi I want to execute a sql statement...I am not a pro in sql and I want to this --->

```
SELECT SUM(Mieter.Auszugsdatum - Mieter.Einzugsdatum) * FROM Mieter WHERE Auszugsdatum < NOW()
```

what is wrong?

Comment: what do you expect the end result to be ? try something like `SELECT DATEDIFF(Mieter.Auszugsdatum , Mieter.Einzugsdatum)`

Comment: wie lange er gewohnt hatte eher xD

Comment: evtl als eine neue tabelle mit einer spalte Mietdauer...und da in Tagen oder in der Richtung

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysql's build in [DATEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function instead:

```
SELECT 
*, DATEDIFF(Mieter.Auszugsdatum, Mieter.Einzugsdatum) as Zeitraum
FROM Mieter 
WHERE Auszugsdatum < NOW()
```

Comment: no it doesn't work ---> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM Mieter WHERE Auszugsdatum < NOW() LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1 ... My Date is in this format: 2014-10-01

Comment: And if you want to sum up the total number of days between the two dates you can sum(datediff(Mieter.Auszugsdatum, Mieter.Einzugsdatum) ...

Comment: Try it without the `,*` please @Tarasov

Comment: The Auszugsdatum and Einzugsdatum columns must be defined as Dates. Otherwise you need to convert the strings representing the dates into to Date type.

Comment: Are the columns defined as dates? @Tarasov The error was the ,* after datediff, please try it with the updated query.